# Controller and Filter modules in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Hello I'm started to learn AngrularJS from strach and I have problem with basic two modules and basic filter:

```
<body ng-app="myapp">

<div ng-controller="MyController" >

{{1+1}} 

<div>Filtered: {{myData.text | myFilter:2:5}}</div>
</div>
<script>
angular.module("myapp", [])
.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
$scope.myData = {};
$scope.myData.text = "balsalaskdlas";
});

angular.module("myapp", []).filter('myFilter', function() {

    return function(stringValue, startIndex, endIndex) {
        return stringValue.substring(parseInt(startIndex), parseInt(endIndex));
    };
});

</script>

</body>
```

But this code gives me error : "Argument 'MyController' is not a function, got undefined"

And in HTML browser as page I saw:

```
{{1+1}}
Filtered: {{myData.text | myFilter:2:5}}
```

What is wrong with these code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
angular.module("myapp", [])
```

The above line defines a new module, named "myapp", and overwrite the previously defined module. If you want to get a reference to the module and add a filter to it, use

```
angular.module("myapp").filter(...)
```

Comment: Thanks That was a Issue

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring the module twice and you are missing an ending in the ng-controller-div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x"     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.17/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.2.17"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myapp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController" >
      {{1+1}} 
      <div>Filtered: {{myData.text | myFilter:2:5}}</div>
    </div>

    <script>
    var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
    app.controller("MyController", function($scope) {
      $scope.myData = {};
      $scope.myData.text = "balsalaskdlas";
    });

    app.filter('myFilter', function() {
        return function(stringValue, startIndex, endIndex) {
          return stringValue.substring(parseInt(startIndex), parseInt(endIndex));
        };
    });

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```